# Module 'ng' has no exported member 'IDirective'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, visual-studio-code

I am implemeting **Angular 1** directive with **TypeScript**. Everything looks fine, it compiles, but I receive the following error in my Visual Studio Code editor:

> Module 'ng' has no exported member 'IDirectiveFactory'.

Here is my code:

```
class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {

  constructor(a, b) {
   ......
  }

  static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
    const directive = (a, b) => new MyDirective(a, b);
    directive.$inject = ['a', 'b'];
    return directive;
  }

  ///more code
};

angular.module('module1').directive('mydirective', MyDirective.factory());
```

I tried to replace `ng.IDirectiveFactory` with `angular.IDirectiveFactory`, and that worked fine but the documentation says I should use the `ng` module instead of the `angular` one.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're importing angular this way:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

They probably import it in the documentation like this:

```
import * as ng from 'angular';
```

They do it because it's shorter :).